# Realtek LAN Driver for Windows 10 install

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, drivers

My neighbor indicates her Gateway SX2110G Windows 10 returns "[No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed.](https://appuals.com/fix-no-boot-disk-detected-disk-failed/)"  The drive will be replaced with an SSD with a fresh Win-10 install.  The key is to have a working LAN driver so that Windows 10 can pull other drivers from the network / internet.

The [Gateway Support Site](https://www.gateway.com/gw/en/CA/content/drivers-downloads) indicates Win-8 Atheros and Realtek LAN driver:

[image]

While I would like to think that Windows 10 has Realtek drivers included on the install media, let's assume it does not for this question: Will manually adding the Win-8 Realtek driver provide network connectivity so that Windows 10 can download the latest drivers?

Answer (score 1):

> Will manually adding the Win-8 Realtek driver to provide network connectivity so that Windows 10 can download the latest drivers?

The drivers on that page are not compatible with Windows 10.  **You need to download the proper drivers directly from the Windows Update catalog.**

- [Download 6.0.8934.1 CAB for HDA "64-bit Windows 10 version 1903 and later Servicing Drivers" - 149.4 MB](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2020/06/989f3696-5528-4b3e-b5c4-77e7bc3ec672_7e12a600cdfe2176ef6efd619809571e9ae42cc2.cab)
- [Download 6.0.8924.1 CAB for HDA "32-bit Windows 10 version 1903 and later Servicing Drivers" - 88.8 MB](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2020/05/74bab136-672b-4fca-9b7c-06219f5edcd7_05fc2f5fd69dd1d60835568320f3a00dbd7b20d2.cab)

In order to install a driver from the file provide the following steps.

> 1. Extract the cab file to a directory
> 2. Open Device Manager
> 3. Select the device and Click `Update Driver Software...`
> 4. Browse and select the folder where you have extracted the cab
> 5. Install the driver

Source:

- [How to Install a CAB File in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/66346-install-cab-file-windows-10-a.html)
- [Latest Realtek HD Audio Driver Version](https://www.tenforums.com/sound-audio/135259-latest-realtek-hd-audio-driver-version-2-a.html)

Comment: You might have to use a older version of the driver, since I know nothing about the audio device, I can't perform adequate research.